# I'm getting a NoMethod Error on my links#index views page when I try and update and/or edit an Account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using the Devise gem and getting a NoMethod error when trying to update an account. It centres around Users being able to use their name on the account as part of the Strong Parameters I've inputted into the application controller. I'm being told I have an undefined method 'name' as a result.

The error centres on this piece of **code** in my views page:

```
    <h2>
      <%= link_to link.title, link %><br>
      <small class="author">Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(link.created_at) %> by <%= link.user.name %></small>
    </h2>
```

And this **code** in my application controller:

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name

end
```

Comment: Based on the current info all I can say is that you have a link record that is not associated with any user. So in `<%= link.user.name %>`, `user` is `nil` and a `nil` object doesn't have a method called `name`.

Comment: How do I rectify this? Should I clear my database? (I saw this suggested on a similar issue).

Comment: You can just delete the links that don't have a user (i.e. `links.user_id is null`). And you should make sure that you cannot create links without having a user associated. And when you delete a user, you should also delete dependant links.